# How to set the WordPress logo programmatically with PHP

Tags: php, functions, import, logo

I am working on a WordPress theme. We implemented "One Click Demo Import" for the theme users to quickly populate their new blank theme with some dummy data.

My question is, how can I set the logo of a WordPress site with PHP? This needs to be done inside an action. I call `add_action( 'pt-ocdi/after_import', 'kinsley_ocdi_after_import_setup' );` and in the `kinsley_ocdi_after_import_setup` I need to run this processing code.

This seems like it should not be hard to do, but I cannot find a "set_logo" function. Is this possible using just WordPress core? None of the `*_custom_logo()` functions allow data to be altered.

What I am looking for inside the action function:

```
// set logo
if (!has_custom_logo()) {
    // set logo of site to an image located at http://www.example.com/myimage.png
}
```

Answer (score 2):

The logo is a theme mod, so you can set it with `set_theme_mod( 'custom_logo', $value );`, but the value needs to be an attachment ID, so you'll need to upload it first.

If you don't want to upload anything, you can use the `get_custom_logo()` filter to provide your own HTML for the logo. If you want to mimic the way WordPress does it, just make sure to include the link `custom-logo` classes:

```
function wpse_304465_custom_logo( $html ) {
    if ( $html == '' ) {
        $html = sprintf( 
            '<a href="%1$s" class="custom-logo-link" rel="home" itemprop="url">%2$s</a>',
            esc_url( home_url( '/' ) ),
            '<img src="http://www.example.com/myimage.png" class="custom-logo" itemprop="logo">'
        );
    }

    return $html;
}
add_filter( 'get_custom_logo', 'wpse_304465_custom_logo' );
```